# email as username, case-sensitive email address

Tags: django

I use email address as a username in my Django application

`USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` but email field is case-sensitive so:

`test@example.com` and `TEST@EXAMPLE.COM` are saved as two different users. It's normal or should I validate this somehow?

Comment: I found a [nice article](http://girders.org/blog/2013/01/31/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses/) regarding email addresses as usernames and RFC compliance. It also covers the topic you asked for.

Comment: New URL https://girders.org/2013/01/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses.html for the nice article dahrens mentioned.

Comment: Here is the url for the above article that works as of now: https://girders.org/2013/01/31/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses/

Answer (score 2):

Lowercase the email before using it for operations like saving, comparing etc.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.email = self.email.lower()
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should validate both email as same user and try to save username in `lowercase` always.

If you keep both email as different user, there are some usecases that need be handled manually, and it will increase overhead.

> - Suppose `test@example.com` mistakenly tried to login with `Caps` on, in that case he can never get access to his account.
> - You have to alway keep in mind not to use case-insensitive lookups on `username` field like `iexact`, `icontains` during development.